# For cache-control to expire in 10 years, is using doc.css?v=128 exactly the same as doc_v128.css?

Tags: http-headers, cache-control

When using `Cache-Control` and `Expires` header so that a page won't expire in 10 years:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=315360000
Expires: Sun, 19 Jul 2020 18:06:32 GMT
```

will using line 1 have identical result as line 2?

```
<link href="/public/doc.css?v=128" ... >

<link href="/public/doc_v128.css" ... >
```

I was thinking maybe some browser will take the `?v=128` as a somewhat more dynamic content and reload it before the 10 year expiration?

Otherwise, both files will expire in 10 years and when there is changes to the CSS, the `128` can be updated to 129 and it will be loaded for sure and have a brand new 10 year expiration date?

(the same goes for javascript `.js` files)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a changing value in the querystring may work against you.  According to Google's Page Speed [Optimize caching](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/caching.html) Performance Best Practice:

> **Don't include a query string in the URL for static resources**
>
> Most proxies, most notably Squid up
>   through version 3.0, do not cache
>   resources with a "?" in their URL even
>   if a Cache-control: public header is
>   present in the response. To enable
>   proxy caching for these resources,
>   remove query strings from references
>   to static resources, and instead
>   encode the parameters into the file
>   names themselves.

Also, you may want to reconsider 10 years.  According to the [Header Field Definitions > Expires](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.21) section of RFC 2616, one year is the max.

> To mark a response as "never expires,"
>   an origin server sends an Expires date
>   approximately one year from the time
>   the response is sent. HTTP/1.1 servers
>   SHOULD NOT send Expires dates more
>   than one year in the future.

Comment: why the "Should not"?  For example, in the book High Performance Web Sites by a chief tech person in Yahoo, it describes a usage to set the expiration to 10 years, by using both `Expires` header and `Cache-Control max-age`

Comment: (the name of the author is Steve Sounders)

Comment: "Given the frequency with which users clear their cache and fill their cache, setting an expiration date one year or ten years in the future might not make much difference" - http://developer.yahoo.net/blog/archives/2007/05/high_performanc_2.html